# Android: Image button is not alligned to right

Tags: android, button

I want my image button  to be placed on the rt side bottom of the scree. but it is not getting visible.Please see the code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Date of Birth:" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dateButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="Select date" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Manual labour" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ed1"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Gender :" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioSex"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioMale"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Male" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioFemale"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Female" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Occupation" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/occuaption_arrays"
            android:prompt="@string/occupation_prompt" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Monthly Income" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/income_arrays"
            android:prompt="@string/income_prompt" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>



    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:contentDescription="dfg"
        android:src="@drawable/next"
        android:visibility="visible"/>
```

I have tried using RelativeLayout as parent and add attribute    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" and android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

My image is very large.Is that can be a problem?

Comment: hey your code is working for me very much fine. But you try the same code by not setting src for ImageButton in your code. if it worked then problem is with Image

Comment: If you want to place an object at the right/left/top/bottom/over/under you should coinsider using RelativeLayout.

Comment: Yes,when i changed image,Its working.But why this is a problem since iam adjusting it with layout_height and layout_width?

Comment: @siraj Your problem is solved or not?

Comment: solved . but No idea why it is not working for my previous image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have setted match-parent to width and height of TableLayout. So TableLayout overlaps ImageButton

use below code...

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap-content"
```